# Sidekiq daemon process dies after some second

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, process, sidekiq, capistrano3

```
namespace :sidekiq do
  task :quiet do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "pgrep -f 'sidekiq'| xargs kill -9 -USR1"
    end
  end
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "cd #{current_path} bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -d"
    end
  end
end

after 'deploy:starting', 'sidekiq:quiet'
after 'deploy:reverted', 'sidekiq:restart'
after 'deploy:published', 'sidekiq:restart'
```

This is my script I am using in `deploy.rb`

It kills the process properly it also creates a daemon process but within few second it kills. And I am using capistrano for deployment.

I think so the daemon process is child process and capistrano deployment is parent process so after completing deployment it kills the child process(i.e daemon process).

Please help me I am really stuck from last 1 week.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the module [capistrano-sidekiq](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq). This works great.

Also you have two commands in one execution, but there is a missing `&&`:

```
execute "cd #{current_path} && bundle exec sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml -d"
```

Comment: I will try capistrano-sidekiq and get back to you.
But one thing I also added '&&' between the two command but it still get dies.
I checked the process is created but killed after few second. I read the document where I see the daemon process (i.e child process) is killed as soon as deployment process is over (i.e parent process).

If you anything about this so please let me know

Comment: try **run** instead of **execute**:

Comment: I find what the problem is my pty set to true. I set pty to false but it fails to start nginx server.

execute :sudo, "service nginx restart"
It giving me this Sorry, you must have a TTY to run sudo

Again I am stuck please help

Comment: Try capistrano-sidekiq gem. It works well with pty true.